# regex e-mail mask for look ahead and look behind of the @

Tags: java, regex

how can ı mask an e-mail with regex for java like this
foo@bar.com
f*o@b*****m
ı used this 
`String maskedEmail = email.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");`

but ı get this: f*o@bar.com
my problem:ı cant control after @
ı want to control it like before @ at the same time.
ıt is important for banned words without e-mail verification

Comment: Adjusting my former solution, you may use [`replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*[^@]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?!$)", "*")`](https://regex101.com/r/qg72Rm/2)

Comment: @SilvanBregy That is validation, here, OP wants to *mask*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Next time I read the question a bit more precisely.